# Emacs hangs when typing in haskell-mode

Tags: emacs, haskell-mode

I have been using haskell-mode for some time now with no problems.

Recently emacs has started to hang for quite a while whenever I type in something in haskell-mode, say 10-15 seconds, and then returns to "normal". I can navigate around and switch buffers normally, but typing (in the haskell buffer) somehow halts emacs completely.

I don't recall changing anything, haskell- or emacs-wise, before this started occuring.

Moreover, it seems very difficult to track down. I have the following error message, but I'm not even sure that it related to this issue:

> Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 1285) signaled (error
>   "Error in syntax_table logic for to-the-end intervals")

The freezes/hangs only occur in haskell-mode, everything else seems to act normally.

Is there a way I can find out what is blocking, and from there probably get closer to figuring it out?

Comment: Have you verified that it's definitely Haskell mode by uninstalling Haskell mode and seeing if you can still hang?

Comment: Yes, if I uninstall haskell mode, the same files don't hang. Reinstalling haskell mode causes the hangs to reappear, starting with a long hang when opening the file.

Comment: You hit a long-standing bug in Emacs's C code.  If you can find a way to reproduce it reliably, then please please pretty please `M-x report-emacs-bug` and give us the recipe.

Comment: This might be the same problems I'm experiencing, it seems to be bound to when i write a top level definition. Usually if i type `f :: Int<RET>` emacs hangs for a long time, if I instead type `f = ()` and then move up a line to write the type definition it works, but i noticed that also hung emacs recently. I've tried different indentation modes and get the same problems

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the same as [this bug](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/182). It has been fixed (in [this commit](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/commit/aeabf0bd2df9c13984c63d50f7b96af35e72c849)) but I don't think any released versions have the fix, so you'll have to either download the latest source from git or apply the patch manually.